# Is wearing Covid-19 masks idolatry for a Jew? Why or why not?

Tags: halacha, talmud-gemara

Are Covid-19 masks idolatry why or why not? I heard from an evil source (this guy is a freemason: https://www.bitchute.com/video/PHqFlPqV8AZV/ and a messianic Jew (according to his website)) that masks are idols from an xtian monastery (from a documentary-style video he produced with a coworker?, it's on Youtube?, used to be). What does Rabbinic Judaism think of this? Please "approach with [extreme] caution", to quote someone, my references and this kind of research in general, including the people. You can go too far too quickly. Here is this person's blog: https://southernisraelite.wordpress.com. He is a Messianic Jew, so please be wary of his antagonism/hatred? towards Rabbinic Judaism and its followers. Please site your sources in your reply. Please accept my apology in advance if I'm intentionally causing a fellow Jew (or multiple) to sin.

Answer (score 0):

I just happened to notice an article about this in the Mishpacha Magazine this week in an interview with Rabbi Hauer and this topic came up. (I didn't read the site you linked to, just the question about wearing masks)

https://mishpacha.com/the-people-come-first/

Here's the relevant excerpt;

“To us at the OU,” Rabbi Hauer reflects, “it was important that our position be one with real integrity, not an on-the-fly, decide-on-the-spot way of dealing with it. Eventually, the pandemic will end, with Hashem’s help, but who can put the genie back in the bottle in terms of honesty, respect for government, reverence for human life?

There is resolve in his voice. “Training ourselves to ignore the government isn’t good. Cheapening, even by a bit, the value of human life, isn’t good. So at the direction of the OU poskim, we followed the CDC guidelines throughout and will continue to do so. Wearing a mask in shul isn’t comfortable? That’s only because you didn’t work hard enough to invest people with a sense of kedushah, of dignity and truth, in being careful. If we do our jobs, our mispalelim will see it as part of the avodah.